# Call templated member function vs. templated global function to create object in generic factory

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers

Having searched online for different approaches to the Factory pattern, I've implemented my own version which I'm quite satisfied with. The *Register* member function creates a function pointer for the template type, storing it in a *std::map* using the index as the key. This below code compiles and runs without hassle (Windows 7 64-bit, Code::Blocks 10.05 with GCC).

```
#ifndef OBJECT_FACTORY_HPP
#define OBJECT_FACTORY_HPP

#include <map>

namespace internal {
    template<typename BaseType, typename ObjectType>
    BaseType* CreateFunction() {
        return new ObjectType;
    }
}

template<typename BaseType, typename IndexType>
class ObjectFactory {
    public:
        ObjectFactory();

        template<typename ObjectType>
        bool Register(const IndexType& index);

        bool Unregister(const IndexType& index);

        BaseType* Create(const IndexType& index);

    private:
        typedef BaseType* (*creationCallback)();
        typedef std::map<IndexType, creationCallback> Registry;
        Registry registry;

//    private:
//        template<typename ObjectType>
//        BaseType* CreateFunction();
};

template<typename BaseType, typename IndexType>
ObjectFactory<BaseType, IndexType>::ObjectFactory() {
    registry.clear();
}

template<typename BaseType, typename IndexType>
template<typename ObjectType>
bool ObjectFactory<BaseType, IndexType>::Register(const IndexType& index) {
    if (registry.find(index) != registry.end())
        return false;

    registry[index] = &internal::CreateFunction<BaseType, ObjectType>;
    // registry[index] = &CreateFunction<ObjectType>; <-- FAILS!
    return true;
}

template<typename BaseType, typename IndexType>
bool ObjectFactory<BaseType, IndexType>::Unregister(const IndexType& type) {
    if (registry.find(type) == registry.end())
        return false;

    return (registry.erase(type) == 1);
}

template<typename BaseType, typename IndexType>
BaseType* ObjectFactory<BaseType, IndexType>::Create(const IndexType& index) {
    if (registry.find(index) == registry.end())
        return NULL;

    return registry[index]();
}

//template<typename BaseType, typename IndexType>
//template<typename ObjectType>
//BaseType* ObjectFactory<BaseType, IndexType>::CreateFunction() {
//    return new ObjectType();
//}

#endif
```

My original approach was to have *CreateFunction* as a private member to hide it from users (look at the commented sections, note the non-member function takes an additional template argument). However, this fails with the following error messages, all pointing to the line where I store the function pointer in the *Register* member function:

```
In member function 'bool ObjectFactory<BaseType, IndexType>::Register(const IndexType&) [with ObjectType = Triangle, BaseType = Shape, IndexType = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]':|
instantiated from here
error: no matches converting function 'CreateFunction' to type 'class Shape* (*)()'|
error: candidates are: template<class ObjectType> BaseType* ObjectFactory::CreateFunction() [with ObjectType = ObjectType, BaseType = Shape, IndexType = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]|
```

I wrote a small test client for testing:

```
#include "ObjectFactory.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
    public:
        Shape() {}
        virtual void print() { std::cout << "At heart, I'm a shape"; }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
    public:
        Triangle() {}
        void print() { Shape::print(); std::cout << ", but I'm truly a triangle" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ObjectFactory<Shape, std::string> objectFactory;

    objectFactory.Register<Triangle>("triangle");

    Shape* triangle = objectFactory.Create("triangle");
    triangle->print();

    delete triangle;

    return 0;
}
```

Is this even possible? I feel it should be, and I understand that I'm somehow calling the incorrect member function, but I'm can't see why. On a related note, since someone might mention it, I plan on using *boost::shared_ptr* for the allocation instead of the plain new operator ;) Any other advice or suggestions about the implementation are also welcome.

Comment: `BaseType* CreateFunction() { return new ObjectType; }` should be `std::unique_ptr<BaseType> CreateFunction() { std::unique_ptr<BaseType> p(new ObjectType()); return p; }`.  Just say "no" to `delete`.

Comment: If you read the last paragraph of my post, you can see I already plan to use boost::shared_ptr. I've already had my fair share of memory leaks, so I agree with your last statement. Also reminded me I should read up on std::unique_ptr, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From within our file, we *anonymize* our namespace:

```
// namespace internal {  
   namespace          {
    template<typename BaseType, typename ObjectType> 
    BaseType* CreateFunction() { ... }  
}
```

The non-static function can now be called as originally written, without the namespace qualification:

```
// registry[index] = &internal::CreateFunction<ObjectType>;  
   registry[index] =           &CreateFunction<ObjectType>;
```

The file-scoped `CreateFunction` function is invisible to code outside of the translation unit and is called only by the class `ObjectFactory`.

This approximates well the `private` access specifier for the `CreateFunction`(from within the `ObjectFactory`) proposed in the question.

Comment: That's also a very nice and slightly cleaner approach (you forgot the first template argument though). Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

The creating function should be a static member:

```
template<typename ObjectType> static BaseType* CreateFunction();
```

(the above code, without the `static`, is commented-out in your example).

Now your other commented-out code is valid:

```
registry[index] = &CreateFunction<ObjectType>;
```

---

Edit: to clear up some confusion:

The problem here is mostly in syntax. Templates and `private` are not important here, so let's simplify the situation:

```
struct ObjectFactory {
    void CreateFunction() {std::cout << "message";}
    void AnotherFunction()
    {
        ... = &CreateFunction; // what's that?
    }
};
```

If `CreateFunction` is a nonstatic member function, the syntax `&CreateFunction` is incorrect; i guess that gcc complains just about that. To make things worse, however, MS Visual Studio tries to "help" you by internally "correcting" the syntax to `&ObjectFactory::CreateFunction` and trying to use that; but it fails with unintelligible error messages (the fact that you have templates aggravates them even more).

I am not sure about the Visual Studio part (i remember having such trouble with MSVC 6 a few years ago; a newer version of Visual Studio doesn't have this problem).

Comment: The code's commented out because it was the original approach. The new one uses the global function declared inside the internal namespace.

Comment: @NordCoder I understood your question as "my commented-out code doesn't work; how can i fix it?"

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to rephrase my question.

I just tried it, and it works flawlessly, thanks a lot :) I don't see why this should be invalid syntax (even though GCC tells me it is) or why the private member funtion should not work. Maybe GCC does the same thing as MS Visual Studio? Declaring the function pointer typedef as typedef BaseType*(ObjectFactory::*creationCallback)(); instead generates more complicated errors.

Comment: Apologies for the spam but that was indeed my question, I just chose to comment out one approach to avoid duplicating the code to show both approaches. Might have been more clear though.

Comment: Right. I think I follow, thanks for the clarification. What would the correct syntax be then? Thinking a bit more about it, I thought I might be able to use boost::function: `typedef std::map<IndexType, boost::function<boost::shared_ptr<BaseType> (ObjectFactory*, void)>> Registry;
Registry registry;
// ...
registry[index] = &ObjectFactory::CreateFunction<ObjectType>;
// ...
return registry[index](*this, void);`

Not sure if this would work (I'm not by far a Boost expert)...Note that I'm also using boost::shared_ptr here (I managed to get that to work meanwhile).

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that. Most certainly does not work haha :)